# Multiple javascript frameworks in one webpage conflict

Tags: jquery

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/accordion_glam.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.txt"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("a.switch_thumb").toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass("swap");
    $("ul.display").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("fast").addClass("thumb_view");
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("swap");
    $("ul.display").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("fast").removeClass("thumb_view");
    });
});

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordion.js"></script>
```

two scripts in one page out of which only one works..pls help...wat to do..??

Answer (score 2):

You are including both jquery and prototype. Check out the post about using [jQuery with other libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)